# Bash command with LInux

Tags: linux, bash

Im new in Linux command and trying to follow a tutorial to find matching string in csv in this tutorial https://github.com/maxharlow/tutorials/tree/master/find-connections-with-fuzzy-matching.

```
$ csvmatch \
    forbes-billionaires.csv \
    forbes-china-billionaires.csv \
    --fields1 name \
    --fields2 name \
    > billionaires-from-china.csv
```

Im getting this error message:

```
-bash: billionaires-from-china.csv: Permission denied
```

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: you have no write permissions at the location you do the redirection, use */tmp* for instance and it should work: */tmp/billionaires-from-china.csv*

Comment: Try with `sudo` or change permissions of the current directory.

Comment: @selmansamet? can you give me details? Im newbie to this :/!

Comment: sudo chmod -R 0755 /path/to/your-csv-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your code on this way to write in directory where everyone have permissions:

```
csvmatch \
    forbes-billionaires.csv \
    forbes-china-billionaires.csv \
    --fields1 name \
    --fields2 name \
    > /tmp/billionaires-from-china.csv
```